# Changing ApplicationInsights.config filename to ApplicationInsights.MyProjectName.config

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I am setting up a HumbleObject [Composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121286/1977871) project. So I need to place two projects in the same folder and not separate project folders. I have [renamed each of the packages.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513284/1977871) to packages.MyProjectName.config. This works fine.

With VS2015, we have ApplicationInsights and now I am not clear what to do with ApplicationInsights.config file. I am not clear what is the purpose of the ApplicationInsights, and moreover it has got scripts folder also associated with it.

My question is how to manage two *projects with applicationInsights* within the same folder? I will try renaming **ApplicationInsights.config** to **ApplicationInsights.MyProjectName.config**. Can any one please throw some light as to how this impact the solution or application insights in general?

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationInsights is [expecting](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/c3a6b645b294ccd569d4c82530abb82d6054557f/src/Core/Managed/Net40/Extensibility/Implementation/Platform/PlatformImplementation.cs#L31) the file to be named ApplicationInsights.config but it is reading it from the output directly. So you can customize your build script to store the file in your project with any name you like as long as it is copied as ApplicationInsights.config to the output directory.